# ASP.NET core MVC Popup Modal with data from model from view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

Goal:
I'm trying to make a page that has the user enter in an address, then click a button that will verify it with a FedEx API. With the new verified address (now with the extra postal code from FedEx), I want to have the user verify that the new address is correct using a modal popup all without reloading the page.

Problem: I've gotten most of the way, but I've gotten stuck getting the data from the view to the controller. It passes a null model instead of what the user input into the fields.

This is the form the user will fill out:
[image: Form]

Here's the controller: [image: Controller]

Here's the view:

```
@model AirmotionEcommerceWebsite.Models.Home.DeliveryAddressModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shipping Address";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br />
<div class="container">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
    <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div id="PlaceHolderHere"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Name</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Attention To</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strAttnTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strAttnTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Street</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strStreet1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strStreet1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Street 2</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strStreet2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strStreet2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>City</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @{
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dataItems = ViewBag.states;
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>State</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State.IntStateId, dataItems, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State.IntStateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Zip</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strZip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strZip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ajax-method="get" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#ValidateAddress" 
                    data-url="@Url.Action("GetValidationOnAddress", new { model = Model })">Verify Address</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<script>



    $(function () {
        var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
        $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            $j.get(url).done(function (data) {
                PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
                PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
            })
        })

        //PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        //  var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        //  var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        //  var sendData = form.serialize();
        //})
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the fields need to be in a form.  You can use the helper [Html.BeginForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: @hijinxbassist I tried to add that and it didn't change anything. should I add any attributes to the begin form?

Comment: When you debug your jQuery, does your url have all the parameters of the form?

Comment: If you don't want to do the manual work, add the form tag and change your button type from "button" to "submit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the `jQuery` code is not populating the model that gets sent back to the `controller`. If that's is the case, you can try changing the containing `div` to a `form`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
    <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div id="PlaceHolderHere"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Name</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Attention To</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strAttnTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strAttnTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Street</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strStreet1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strStreet1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Street 2</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strStreet2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strStreet2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>City</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @{
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dataItems = ViewBag.states;
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>State</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State.IntStateId, dataItems, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State.IntStateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Zip</h5>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strZip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strZip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ajax-method="get" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#ValidateAddress" 
                    data-url="@Url.Action("GetValidationOnAddress", new { model = Model })">Verify Address</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

And then modifying your `jQuery` code to serialize all the fields in the form:

```
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        // get the form containing the submit button
        var form = $(this).closest('form')
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        // serialize all the fields in the form
        var model = form.serialize();
        // the the request to the url along with the form (model) data
        $j.get(url, model).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    })
```

Comment: That was it! The form.serialize(); was the thing I was missing mostly. Thanks! Now just to get it to actually show up..

Comment: @ScottUphus glad I could help. You can try opening the modal via `jQuery` so in your `done` function you can try something like `$('#ValidateAddress').modal('show');` You will have to replace the body of the modal with the `partialView` that you're retuning.

Comment: I'm going to open another question for this. would you please check it out?

Comment: @ScottUphus sure no problem.